# React return multiple variables from json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to refactor a react project I'm working on.  The file is getting pretty bulky so I wanted to break it up into different files.  My original file app.js contains this state:

```
this.state = {
  selectProduct: [],
  quantityProduct: [],
  colorsProduct: [],
  stockProduct: [],
  turnaroundProduct: [],
  coatingProduct: [],
  attributeProduct: [],
  attributeMetaProduct: [],
}
```

I then run a function to do a fetch request and update the state with this:

```
pullProductDetails = () => {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_details/fetch/36')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const quantityDetails = json.productQuanties.map((quantityDetail) => {
        quantityDetail.selected = false;
    });
    const colorDetails = json.productColor.map((colorDetail) => {
        colorDetail.selected = false;
    });
    const stockDetails = json.productPaperStock.map((stockDetail) => {
        stockDetail.selected = false;
    });
    const turnaroundDetails = json.productTurnaround.map((turnaroundDetail) => {
        turnaroundDetail.selected = false;
    });

    if (json.productCoating.length > 0) {
      const coatingDetails = json.productCoating.map((coatingDetail) => {
          coatingDetail.selected = false;
      }) }
    if (json.productAttributeMeta.length > 0) {
      const attributeMetaDetails = json.productAttributeMeta.map((attributeMetaDetail) => {
          attributeMetaDetail.selected = false;
      }) }

    this.setState(
      {
        quantityProduct: [...this.state.quantityProduct, ...json.productQuanties],
        colorsProduct: [...this.state.colorsProduct, ...json.productColor],
        stockProduct: [...this.state.stockProduct, ...json.productPaperStock],
        turnaroundProduct: [...this.state.turnaroundProduct, ...json.productTurnaround],
        coatingProduct: [...this.state.turnaroundProduct, ...json.productCoating],
        attributeProduct: [...this.state.attributeProduct, ...json.productAttribute],
        attributeMetaProduct: [...this.state.attributeMetaProduct, ...json.productAttributeMeta],
      },
      () => {console.log(this.state)}
    );
      });
}
```

To slim down my app.js file I created a new file for the above code like so:

// here we fetch api to get each drop down produt details

```
export const pullProductDetails = () => {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_details/fetch/36')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const quantityDetails = json.productQuanties.map((quantityDetail) => {
        quantityDetail.selected = false;
    });
    const colorDetails = json.productColor.map((colorDetail) => {
        colorDetail.selected = false;
    });
    const stockDetails = json.productPaperStock.map((stockDetail) => {
        stockDetail.selected = false;
    });
    const turnaroundDetails = json.productTurnaround.map((turnaroundDetail) => {
        turnaroundDetail.selected = false;
    });

    if (json.productCoating.length > 0) {
      const coatingDetails = json.productCoating.map((coatingDetail) => {
          coatingDetail.selected = false;
      }) }
    if (json.productAttributeMeta.length > 0) {
      const attributeMetaDetails = json.productAttributeMeta.map((attributeMetaDetail) => {
          attributeMetaDetail.selected = false;
      }) }

      return [quantityDetails, colorDetails, stockDetails, turnaroundDetails, coatingDetails, attributeMetaDetails];

      });
}
```

In the above code I'm attempting to return each one of those variables with the json data so I can use it to set state but in my console it says the variable doesn't exist.  I also tried running a console from the js file and it says undefined:

```
console.log(quantityDetails);
```

I would expect to be able to access the variables since I'm returning them but I'm unable to do so.  Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

```
const quantityDetails = json.productQuanties.map((quantityDetail) => {
```

Quanties => Quantities maybe?

If it's not a typo i wouldn't know why.